# sound stopped working on Ubuntu (Netbook)

Tags: 16.04, sound, ubuntu-netbook

I'm using a chromebook, and I can't play sound because the drivers aren't supported on chromebook (I'm using 16.04). Any way around this?

Terminal output:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04] (rev 0e)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz    SUSPENDED
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster There you go! Also none of the channels are muted. :)

Comment: please, post `dmesg` output

Comment: This is from official Ubuntu Community Help Documentation. It Helped fix my sound once when it wasn't working. You can try following the steps. [Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Comment: have you tried booting a live install of GalliumOS and see if the sound works there? It's based on ubuntu and designed for netbooks.... What model is the laptop (braswell, bay trail, etc) ?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Actually I have tried GalliumOS but it still doesn't play sound. My speakers aren't blown out or anything so I have no idea why it would not be working

Answer (score 1):

You could re-install related packages like amarok and of rhythmbox, with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox amarok
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Nope! Nice try but the sound still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

1 - Update your kernel to the latest version, where there might be support for the hardware you are running. Check your kernel version with `uname -a`

2 - Install ALSA by typing

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install alsamixer
```

Start it by typing `alsamixer` in the terminal and use the argument `--upload` to upload full configuration settings to the alsa project or pastebin. This should give everyone including yourself more information about your sound settings.

Alternatively try adjusting the settings within alsamixer and see if any of it helps to bring back the sound. It could be something as simple as that a channel is surpressed.

Comment: This happened: 

`E: Unable to locate package alsamixer`
Also Kernel is fully updated

Comment: apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss

Comment: Nope still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try to do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo alsa force-reload
```

if that won't work then i dont know what will.

Comment: Didn't work :/ I think you may be right; nothing works

Comment: @Hershey Gamer re-install it and see what happens, if that doesn't work, it's a PC problem

Comment: yeah this is probably a pc problem since reinstalling it did nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Install codec with this command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I installed it and the sound still doesn't work. :/